# migrate ffprobe command to ffmpeg-python

Tags: ffmpeg-python

I currently am trying to migrate the following command from ffprobe to ffmpeg-python

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_packets -show_entries stream=nb_read_packets -of csv=p=0 input.mp4
```

I tried the following and it did not work

```
ffmpeg.probe(file_path, v='error', select_streams='v:0', count_packets=True, show_entries=True, stream='nb_read_packets', of=True, csv='p=0')
```

I have tried this inputting it as a dictionary as well

```
ffmpeg.probe(file_path, **{'v':'error', 'select_streams':'v:0', 'count_packets':1, 'show_entries':1, 'stream':'nb_read_packets', 'of':'csv=p=0'})
```

But none of these seem to work, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR Answer

With the way the parameters for the python bindings for ffmpeg-python work, the format of the command you are inputting is incorrect. Instead the following should work for you

```
import ffmpeg, json
out = ffmpeg.probe("input.mp4", cmd='ffprobe', v='error', select_streams='v:0', count_packets=None, show_entries='stream=nb_read_packets')
out["streams"][0]["nb_read_packets"]
```

#### Complete Answer

Digging through the API reference for the ffmpeg-python module, the python binding [ffmpeg.probe](https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/#ffmpeg.probe), states that it will

> Run ffprobe on the specified file and return a JSON representation of
> the output.

Debugging through the [module/source code](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/blob/df129c7ba30aaa9ffffb81a48f53aa7253b0b4e6/ffmpeg/_probe.py#L16), this python binding for [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe-all.html) will always add the command line options `-show_format`, `-show_streams`, `-of json` to your command that you pass in as defined in the
`_probe.py` file.

So for the ffprobe command you provided:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_packets -show_entries stream=nb_read_packets -of csv=p=0 input.mp4
```

will essentially be this command line options after passing through ffmpeg.fprobe:

```
ffprobe -show_format -show_streams -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_packets -show_entries stream=nb_read_packets -of csv=p=0 -of json input.mp4
```

I downloaded an mp4 [video](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4) that was probably a chromecast commercial based on the description. Here's the gist [link](https://gist.github.com/jsturgis/3b19447b304616f18657) that I found it from, and look for the title "For Bigger Escape". I downloaded the file and renamed it input.mp4 to match the example you provided.

After running

```
>ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_packets -show_entries stream=nb_read_packets -of csv=p=0 input.mp4
361
>
```

I get 361.

Now running the command:

```
ffprobe -show_format -show_streams -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_packets -show_entries stream=nb_read_packets -of csv=p=0 -of json input.mp4
```

I get the output

```
{
    "programs": [

    ],
    "streams": [
        {
            "nb_read_packets": "361",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,        
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,       
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "language": "und",
                "handler_name": "VideoHandler"
            }
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "input.mp4",
        "nb_streams": 2,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2",
        "format_long_name": "QuickTime / MOV",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "15.045000",
        "size": "2299653",
        "bit_rate": "1222813",
        "probe_score": 100,
        "tags": {
            "major_brand": "mp42",
            "minor_version": "0",
            "compatible_brands": "isommp42",
            "creation_time": "2013-11-12T06:38:58.000000Z"
        }
    }
}
```

That value of 361 is now in key value of `nb_read_packets`

I tried exactly replicating the command line

```
out= ffmpeg.probe("input.mp4", cmd='ffprobe', v='error', select_streams='v:0', count_packets=None, show_entries='stream=nb_read_packets', of='csv=p=0')
```

in ffmpeg-python, but I keep getting a JSONDecodeError:
[image]

The value of s from the debugger showed this string value:

```
s
'361,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,und,VideoHandler\r\ninput.mp4,2,0,"mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2",QuickTime / MOV,0.000000,15.045000,2299653,1222813,100,mp42,0,isommp42,2013-11-12T06:38:58.000000Z\r\n'
```

My only assumption is with the `-of` or `-print_format` option, some characters were stripped or modified and that is giving the json decoder issues to decode it.
I finally decided to take out the `-of csv=p=0` flag and the following was able to run with no errors

```
import ffmpeg, json
out = ffmpeg.probe("input.mp4", cmd='ffprobe', v='error', select_streams='v:0', count_packets=None, show_entries='stream=nb_read_packets')
value = out["streams"][0]["nb_read_packets"]
print(value)
361
```

#### Side Note

Some of the options that do not have direct parameters following them are defined as `None` because they do not have any parameters. This has been brought up several times in open issues from the github repo, and I have previously [commented](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/issues/608#issuecomment-957781280) on it. It is not stated in the documents, and as far as I know, no PRs are out to update the docs to explicitly state it.

Comment: I went ahead and awarded the bounty, I have no tried your solution yet.  I will mark as correct, or comment when I do.  Thank you

Comment: @nadermx Thx! Hope it works out.